# How to pass a template function as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, parameter-passing

Consider this for a second:

```
template <class T_arr, class T_func>
void iter(T_arr *arr, int len, T_func func)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        func(arr[i]);
    }
}

void display(int a) {
    std::cout << "Hello, your number is: " << a << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{    
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

    iter(arr, 3, display);
    return (0);
}
```

Which works as expected, however, if I try to change the display function to a template:

```
template <class T>
void display(T a) {
    std::cout << "Hello, your number is: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

It stops working and i get this error: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T_func'.

How to make sense of this?

Comment: When you call `iter(arr1, 3, display);`, _which_ `display` do you mean? `display<int>`? `display<std::string>`? `display<double>`? The compiler is not able to figure out that "Oh, `T_func` is supposed to accept a `T_arr` as its argument, so because I've deduced `T_arr = int` I'll try instantiating `double<int>` for `T_func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the template argument for `display` explicitly:

```
iter(arr, 3, display<int>);
```

Or make `iter` taking function pointer:

```
template <class T_arr>
void iter(T_arr *arr, int len, void (*func)(T_arr))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        func(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

then you can

```
iter(arr, 3, display); // template argument gets deduced as int
```

Comment: The deduction part by specifying the signature is great! With `template <class T_arr>
void iter(T_arr *arr, int len, void (*func)(T_arr) = display)` it would even work as a default (if the `display` template has been defined before) and could be called with `iter(arr, 3);`